# String parameter not being populated using URL routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

URL rewriting issue. When i call me url using the following link

```
http://localhost:12719/product/18
```

it works fine the product 18 links to the parameter. However when i call it using the following.

```
http://localhost:12719/product/apple
```

It doesn't map the apple product name to the controller, it thinking that your trying to invoke a action of type apple.

Why does it map numeric and not string to the controller parameter? The controller parameter is an type of string.

Routing are as below.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "product",
    url: "product/{id}/{slug}",
    defaults: new { controller = "product", action = "product", slug = UrlParameter.Optional },
    constraints: new { id = @"\d+" }
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have specified id to be only numeric in the regex specified in the constraint. `constraints: new { id = @"\d+" }` remove it and should work. So since "product" doesnot pass `\d+` test you will get the id as null in the action.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "product",
    url: "product/{id}/{slug}",
    defaults: new { controller = "product", action = "product", slug = UrlParameter.Optional }

);
```

Comment: doesn't work :( is there a way to change the regex type to string? error im getting. The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult

Comment: Change the type of `id` from int to string in your action.